# Application getting Killed when kept in Background for Few minutes

Tags: ios, objective-c

- When I Open my app & do some stuff (Say navigate to certain
  `ViewController`), then I don't Touch the App for few minutes iPhone gets locked(App Goes in `BackGround State)`.
- Now After few
  minutes (about 5 minutes) When I Unlock the iPhone My App get Killed.It
  is not there in Opened State(`Active State`). I need to open it explicitly by clicking App Icon.
- I am not doing anything in `BackGround State`
- One more thing to add is App is not Crashing

Comment: Check the console log.

Comment: If you double tap the _Home_ button does your app show up in the multitasking UI? After you unlock the phone and your app is not foreground anymore.

Comment: Alex@It is there in multitasking UI. Is it a Default behavior.If it is ,Please provide url , it will be very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you checked correctly that your app does not crash, it shows in the multitasking UI and you're not [executing code in the background](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html), then I would say that your app is being terminated by the system (due to memory pressure or something else).

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW7) mentions:

> Apps must be prepared for termination to happen at any time and should
>   not wait to save user data or perform other critical tasks.
>   System-initiated termination is a normal part of an app’s life cycle.
>   The system usually terminates apps so that it can reclaim memory and
>   make room for other apps being launched by the user, but the system
>   may also terminate apps that are misbehaving or not responding to
>   events in a timely manner.
>
> Suspended apps receive no notification when they are terminated; the
>   system kills the process and reclaims the corresponding memory. If an
>   app is currently running in the background and not suspended, the
>   system calls the `applicationWillTerminate:` of its app delegate prior
>   to termination.

So what happened in your scenario is that the app entered the suspended state and after a period of time (those 5 minutes that you mention) the app was terminated by the system.
Take a look at the [Background Transition Cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW24).

If you want to reduce the possibility that your app will get terminated due to memory pressure, then take a look at [What to Do When Your App Enters the Background](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW22), specifically:

> **Free up memory as needed.** Release any cached data that you do not need
>   and do any simple cleanup that might reduce your app’s memory
>   footprint. Apps with large memory footprints are the first to be
>   terminated by the system, so release image resources, data caches, and
>   any other objects that you no longer need. For more information, see
>   Reduce Your Memory Footprint.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure background modes are on from capabilities options (i have worked on a navigation app and keep app alive in background for more than 8 hours for tracking)
in objective C implement following code

```
- (void)backgroundCleanDisk {
    Class UIApplicationClass = NSClassFromString(@"UIApplication");
    if(!UIApplicationClass || ![UIApplicationClass respondsToSelector:@selector(sharedApplication)]) {
        return;
    }
    UIApplication *application = [UIApplication performSelector:@selector(sharedApplication)];
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you
        // stopped or ending the task outright.
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
    [self cleanDiskWithCompletionBlock:^{
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
}
```