# Bluetooth background mode when app is killed

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am use *bluetooth-central* and *bluetooth-peripheral* modes in my iOS application. But how it can work when I kill my app (swipe up)?

Comment: It can't. Your app is dead. You killed it. iOS assumes you don't want it to run any more, so it won't

Comment: You are sure? Are there nothing ways to do this?

Comment: Don't swipe up?

Comment: But it's strange. Imagine that human with problem heart swipe up the application that monitor his heart rate. And application can't send data to hospital if his health condition starts getting worse.

Comment: iOS is not a suitable platform for developing life-critical medical applications.  There are a lot of regulatory approvals required for medical equipment.

Comment: IOS clock update it icon, even if app is closed.

Comment: Apple apps are different.  They can do things that regular apps can't

Comment: @Paulw11, thank you for your answers

Comment: It's possible to do certain things in the background when you app is killed. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html.

This may answer your question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35551294/application-getting-killed-when-kept-in-background-for-few-minutes

Comment: Yes, its says that I have few minutes, but I need more time, as Service in Android, that always running.